# Question about configuring policy for uploading docker image to ECR in Jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, amazon-iam, amazon-ecr

I created a new role for upload docker image to ECR by using Jenkins, I attached this policy I found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/security_iam_id-based-policy-examples.html)

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Sid":"ListImagesInRepository",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "ecr:ListImages"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:123456789012:repository/my-repo"
      },
      {
         "Sid":"GetAuthorizationToken",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken"
         ],
         "Resource":"*"
      },
      {
         "Sid":"ManageRepositoryContents",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
                "ecr:ListImages",
                "ecr:DescribeImages",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
                "ecr:PutImage"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:123456789012:repository/my-repo"
      }
   ]
}
```

I tested in Policy Simulator, it gave me denied:
[image]

I suspect something goes wrong with the ARN, I've only found a URL for ECR repo, but  I changed the format according to the example, can someone help me? Been struggling with it for a very long time now.

Comment: The resource ARN looks correct, assuming the region, account, and repo name are correct. `arn:${Partition}:ecr:${Region}:${Account}:repository/${RepositoryName}`

Comment: yeah but why it shows me denied, and I get permission error in jenkins logs as well.

Comment: Can you post the permissions error from the Jenkins log (edited to remove sensitive data)?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the `Simulation Resource`. You are testing for `*`, but your policy, wisely, doesn't allow all. You should test it for the actual ARN of the resource you need to access.